# Redirect url to previous page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to redirect to previous page in laravel5.2 like URI Referrer in php.

I've tried $request->url(); 
but it gets the current url.

I've a form and list pages.There are many lists that redirects to form.but I want to go to that specific page after submit.

For Ex:There are a Project and Client list. If I go to form from project then it should go to project and if I go to form from client list It should go to client list page after submitting a form.

Comment: redirect()->back();

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thank You for answers.
I've got it now.

set the hidden variable in blade to get previous page url using

```
{{  Form::hidden('url',URL::previous())  }}
```

after that get it by `$request->input('url');` in controller,Then redirect it.

```
return redirect($url)->with('success', 'Data saved successfully!');
```

Answer (score 100):

You should use `return redirect()->back();`

Comment: Use `return redirect()->back();` in a Controller and use `{{ url()->previous() }}` in `.blade.php` View Files

Comment: My `<form>` element's submit is using some post-method based route, if I use this in that route: Would this keep the form's page visible or go back to some URL before the form?

Comment: please hint me... I want to manage this scenario: when the session expired and the user log off then we want to redirect back after login to somewhere there

Answer (score 74):

Inside your template file you can just use:

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

Answer (score 24):

You have a global [back](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects) function:

```
return back();
```

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373967/how-can-i-redirect-back-to-previous-page-after-login-on-vue-and-laravel

Answer (score 16):

**To redirect from template You should use**

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

**To redirect from the controller you should use**

```
return redirect()->back();
```

**or Just**

```
 return back();
```

Comment: You just copied other people's different methods and combined them into one post to steal their points.

Comment: You can say that but the truth is I just explain all methods and explain the difference among methods, where we have to use which method.

Answer (score 6):

As the description of your problem, the simple solution is, you have to use the below code in the controller,

```
return back();
```

or,

```
return redirect()->back();
```

If you want to get the link from where you came from, You can apply the following code in the blade template,

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect back to previous page on Laravel Blade using

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

Example below:

```
<a  href="{{ url()->previous() }}">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></i>
    <span>Back</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should this methods:

**return calling  controller:**

```
return redirect()->action('classcontroller@fuction');
```

**return calling  url:**

```
return redirect('home/dashboard');
```

[REDIRECTS LARAVEL 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects)

Answer (score 2):

**You should use a global function**

```
return back();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Back</a>
```