# How can I redirect back to previous page after login on vue and laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-5.6

I use vue.js 2 and laravel 5.6

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <a v-if="auth" href="javascript:" class="btn btn-default btn-block" @click="add($event)">
        Add
    </a>
    <a v-else href="javascript:" class="btn btn-default btn-block" @click="logout">
        Add
    </a>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                auth: App.authCheck
            }
        },
        methods: {
            add(event) {
               ...
            },
            logout() {
                window.location = '/login?red='+window.location.pathname
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If the user is not logged in, it will call the logout method

I try like the code above, but if user login, it does not redirect to the previous page

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you want the login to redirect to your current page, that `/login` component of yours must make use of the `red=` query param. Is that it?

Comment: @acdcjunior I'm still confused. But seems like that

Comment: What is at `/login` a component of yours or something from laravel? If it's a component, show it.

Comment: You better use vue-router.

Comment: @Dencio Try to answer with a detail answer

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, it is a routes laravel. it's like this : `Route::get('login', function(){
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    })->name('admin.auth.login');
`

Comment: Show the `admin.auth.login` view code.

Comment: @acdcjunior It's login form. The point is like this : `<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
 ....
</form>`

Answer (score -1):

Laravel requires you do do a `POST` request when logging out.

In order to do this you will need the `csrf token` and the `logout url`.

I would pass these 2 as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props) (in a blade template) :

```
<my-component 
    logout-url="{{route('logout')}}" 
    csrf-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</my-component>
```

Then you should add a hidden form to your template and add the appropriate logic:

```
<template>
    <a v-if="auth" href="javascript:" class="btn btn-default btn-block" @click="add($event)">
        Add
    </a>
    <a v-else href="javascript:" class="btn btn-default btn-block" @click="logout">
        Add
    </a>
    <form id="vue-logout-form" v-action="{{ logoutUrl }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrfToken }}">
    </form>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            logoutUrl:{type: String},
            csrfToken:{type: String}
        },
        [...]
        methods: {
            logout() {
                document.getElementById("vue-logout-form").submit();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Basically you will make the post request by calling the `logout()` method