# Laravel two forms submitting to the same controller and redirecting back

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a UsersController which updates user properties.

```
Route::post('users/{userId}', 'App\UsersController@updateUser')->name('user.id.post');
```

If I submit to that route from two different views, is there a way to know where the submission came from and to redirect to that location upon successful updating?

Is there access to the referring route in Laravel to determine where the submission came from so I can send the redirect back to the source dynamically without having to hide some kind of input within the form to tell me where to submit back to?

Comment: This might be a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482742/redirect-url-to-previous-page-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that you can use the global `back` helper function.

just you should  add at the end of your `updateUser` :

```
return back()->withInput();
```

it will redirect you at the previous page.

for more details, check the  Laravel documentation, please [responses#redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#redirects)